# Put a line of string in textarea everytime I click a checkbox

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Basically I want my code to update the textarea as users put a check in a checkboxes inside a table. If a checkbox is checked, a username will be placed in textarea along with line breaks. If unchecked, it will remove from textarea. After that, a button will submit every string inside the textarea.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    <td align="center">
        <form>
            <div style="max-width:50%" class="form-group @if (ViewBag.ErrorMessageDelete != null)
            { <text>has-error</text> } ">
                @Html.TextArea("deleteRequest", string.Empty, 5, 100, null)
                @if (ViewBag.ErrorMessageDelete != null)
                {
                    <span class="help-block">@ViewBag.ErrorMessageDelete</span>
                }
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return confirm ('Removing these members, are you sure?')">Remove User(s)</button>
        </form>
    </td>
}
```

and this is my current checkbox

```
<td align="center" style="width:5%">
    @Html.CheckBox("toBeDeleted", new { onclick = "deleteRequest = deleteRequest + item.username + <br>" });
</td>
```

I used textarea because I want users to be able to input usernames on their own without using checkboxes. Is it possible to do it in MVC ASP.NET in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes it's possible. You just need some Javascript to handle the checkbox being clicked on, and then write the appropriate text into the textarea. Standard webpage stuff, not specific to MVC (and certainly not to the Visual Studio IDE), btw. Did you research this at all?

Comment: Hi. Sorry I am a beginner and currently still learning. I don't have tutor or anything to help me except bunch of stackoverflows and I ask this after my head hurts how to implement checkboxes in my codes.

Comment: "I don't have anything to help me except"...google. You've got google, that should be the first place to research. What did you search for? What did you try? We'll help you, sure, if it looks like you spent some time and effort to help yourself. We're volunteers, our time is no less valuable than yours, yes? Right now we have zero evidence of any research or effort, it seems you're just asking us for the solution. Not saying you didn't search, but there's no evidence of it here. If you didn't even figure out you'd need JavaScript, I guess you didn't search too much though.

Comment: @Henry You can try now my approach. I just updated my answer. I hope that https://jsfiddle.net/dvk2kvxd/8/ this is what you need.

Comment: @ADyson I can't deny I'm looking for solutions here or at least some leads to the solutions but I'm sorry if I pissed you off or something. I know its supposed to be easy but I'm learning on the go here so that's why I just ask without much hope it will be answered.

Comment: @Dzanan yeah the solution is kinda like that although I need it to add a new line instead of just "," and I need the textarea to keep anything typed on new lines after I unchecked and delete the entries. But I should be able to modify your code to suit my needs tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: @Henry I just updated this JSFiddle. It works now with new line. https://jsfiddle.net/dvk2kvxd/16/ Regards

Comment: You didn't annoy me, we get a lot of help vampires on the site who just want their homework done for free without having to lift a finger. So you'll find if you post a question without any obvious attempt to research or try anything for yourself, people will challenge your motives, that's all. You should be able to do enough research to at least piece together an attempt at a solution - find out how to handle a checkbox being checked in Javascript, find out how to write text to a textarea using Javascript. These little steps are all easy to google and find existing examples, and help you start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this with click event. Use change event on checkbox.
You can also try with the array. If the checkbox is checked add item to array, if not remove it. After that convert array to string, and set a value to textarea. Delete and push logic you have to implement by your own.

```
<td align="center" style="width:5%">
    @Html.CheckBox("toBeDeleted", new { onchange="testfunc(this)", data_username = item.username });
</td>



<script>
     var result = [];
        function testfunc(elem) {
            var username = $(elem).attr("data-username");
            if($(elem).is(':checked')) {
                result.push(username )
            }
            else{
                var index = result.indexOf(username);
                if (index > -1) {
                     result.splice(index, 1);
                  }
           }

           $("#deleteRequest").val(result.join("\n"));

    }
   </script>
```